# Finding match, removing the bits I don't want, and then putting it back in

Tags: php, regex, replace, preg-replace, preg-match

I'm trying to parse thru a file and find a particular match, filter it in some way, and then print that data back into the file with some of the characters removed. I've been trying different things for a couple hours with preg slits and preg replace, but my regular express knowledge is limited so I haven't made much progress.

I have a large file that has many instances like this [something]{title:value}.  I want to find everything between "[" and "}" and remove everything besides the "something" bit.

After that parts done I want to find everything between "{" and "}" on everything left like {title:value} and then remove everything besides the "value" part. I'm sure there is some simple method to do this, so even just a resource on how to get started would be helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if I get your meaning right (and haven't touched PHP for months), what about this?

```
$matches = array();

preg_match_all("/\[(.*?)\]\{.*?:(.*?)\}/", $str, $matches);
$something = $matches[1]; // $something stores all texts in the "something" part
$value = $matches[2]; // $value stores all texts in the "value" part
```

---

Doc for [`preg_match_all`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match-all.php)

For the regex pattern `\[(.*?)\]\{.*?:(.*?)\}`:

1. We escapes all the `[`, `]`, `{` and `}` with a slash because these characters have a special meaning in regex, and need an escape for the literal character.
2. `.*?` is a lazy match all, which will match any character until the next character matches the next token. It is used instead of `.*` so that it won't match other symbols
3. `(.*?)` is a capturing group, getting what we need and PHP will put those matches in `$matches` array
4. So the entire thing is - match the `[` character, then any string until getting the `]` character and put it in capturing group 1, then `]{` characters, then any string until getting the `:` character (no capturing group because we don't care.), then match the `:` character, then any string until the `}` character and put it incapturing group 2.

Comment: PHP doesn't have a `g` modifier. Use `preg_match_all()` instead (which you are).

Comment: This is almost perfect. I couldn't get it to work at first, but then I used print_r on the $matches array and realized it's a multidimensional array. So $something = $matches[$x][1] and $value = $matches[x][2]. Thanks for helping me figure this out. Now I need to spend some time and get more familiar with regular expression. :D

Comment: So I'm wondering if I could use this same regex and the $matches array to plug those values back into the original file I want to replace the entire part where it got them from [x]{y:z}. For example, take $matches[0][1] and then replace it in the original string where it had the [x]{y:z}.

Comment: btw just edited the post, I believe we should drop the `PREG_SET_ORDER` so that it returns the full array of matches as noted in the comments in code

Answer (score 0):

You can do it in one shot:

```
$txt = preg_replace('~\[\K[^]]*(?=])|{[^:}]+:\K[^}]+(?=})~', '', $txt);
```

`\K` removes from match result all that have been matched on his left.

The lookahead `(?=...)` *(followed by)* performs a check but add nothing to the match result.